# Jquery - Vertical centering using the parent height works. Sort of

Tags: jquery, css, image, center

So, I've got X number of images to be vertically centered with in a `<ul><li><a> <img> </a></li></ul>` (the class name in the jquery below is the actual `<img>`).
This is working beatufully but... It only takes the first value and applies it to the rest of the images, resulting in the first one being centered and the others not.

I might add that all the images are of different heights and widths. The widths are taken care of as of now, simply by using `text-align: center;` on the anchortag

```
$(window).load(function(){
    var parent_height = $('.tv-list-channel-logo').parent().height();
    var image_height = $('.tv-list-channel-logo').height();
    var top_margin = (parent_height - image_height)/2;
    $('.tv-list-channel-logo').css( 'margin-top' , top_margin);
});
```

Been staring at this for quite some time now and I am surely missing something obvious.

Comment: Have you tried positioning them absolutely inside of a relative container?

Comment: Yes I have, but I should have mentioned in my first post that the images are of different heights and widths.

Comment: Use my suggestion along with the answer from `Ryan P` Below. Loop through each image and perform this calculation using `each`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the images need different values you'll need to loop through them. Try using `$('.tv-list-channel-logo').each( function... )`. Inside `.each`, `this` refers to the current element.

EDIT: Here's an example of `.each`:

```
// `.each` takes each selected element and calls the callback on each one
$('.tv-list-channel-logo').each( function( ) {
    // `this` refers to the current .tv-list-channel-logo element
    var parent_height = $(this).parent().height();
    var image_height = $(this).height();
    var top_margin = (parent_height - image_height)/2;
    $(this).css( 'margin-top' , top_margin);
    // I just replaced all instances of `'.tv-list-channel-logo'` with `this`
} );
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure if this is what you meant or not, but it is not working. `var image_height = $('.tv-list-channel-logo').each().height();`

Comment: I surely have strained something valuable in my brain. I can't figure this one out...

Comment: I answered this on my phone this morning... at work now, so I typed up an example for ya.